# I'm looking at a css sheet for a react page, and many classes are using content to generate images, but content display in VSCode is a 

Tags: css, reactjs

I am digging into an existing reactJS site, and many images are being rendered by using the css content property. I am looking at the css sheet in VSCode, and many classes are appearing with content listed as "". I'm not sure if I need a plugin to view the actual content, but I can't find a way to see it at this point.

I can use alter the content attribute to point to a different image, but want to know where this is being generated so I can alter it at the source. The site is setup to use Contentful, but assets there are called directly on pages, not in css.

```
.fa-discord:after {
  content: "";
}
```

I'd like to be able to track down where this image is being stored or generated. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a **[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)** icon for Discord, and can be found **[here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/discord?style=brands)**. Yes, you need to include Font Awesome on your website if you want to render any of their glyph icons. And you can easily work out whether a website is attempting to use Font Awesome glyph icons or not, as their selectors all start with `fa-` and replace the `content`.

Font Awesome icons are generated through an included CSS file, most commonly located in a folder like `/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

This file uses unicode characters to generate the corresponding glyph representations, and the specific unicode character for the Discord icon is `392`. Thus, `content: "\f392"` will render the relevant glyph icon.

If a box or square shows up instead of an actual glyph, that means that the font you're using doesn't incorporate that particular unicode glyph. Font Awesome rapidly expands its coverage of unicode glyphs, and you will need to update to at least Font Awesome 5.0.0 in order to use the Discord glyph.